# Ways to define portable executable bitness 64 vs 32

Tags: windows, pe, executable, binary

I found several ways to define the bitness of PE.

- `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` contains the/a (how do you choose an article type in such place?) field `Characteristics` that could be checked for `IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE`.
- `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` contains the field `Magic` switched between `IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC`, `IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC` and some `IMAGE_ROM_OPTIONAL_HDR_MAGIC`.
- `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` also contains Machine field that could be checked for

  - 0x8664 - x64
  - 0xaa64 - ARMv8 in 64-bit mode
  - 0x0200 - Intel Itanium processor family
  - 0x0284 - 64-bit Alpha AXP.

<s>Also `SizeOfOptionalHeader` in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` could be checked for one of two specific values.</s>

Are all of them have the same meaning? Are there any difference, specific conditions, exceptional cases?

---

I found that `Machine` field check is indirect way because the field is aimed to processor architecture defining. So it's indirect and unreliable as heuristic.
`SizeOfOptionalHeader` varies even for the same bitness since some image directories can absent.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just check for 64 bit registers in the decomp?

Comment: I look for truth. And I need fast and reliable way for automatic files processing.

Answer (score 3):

`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER->MAGIC` (which is not optional at all :] ) is what determines for the Windows OS Loader to load this as 32bit vs 64bit. Depending on the value at `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER->MAGIC` is how the loader will parse the rest of the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`.

And as stated `SizeOfOptionalHeader` can be use as a cross reference.

The IMAGE_FILE_HEADER->MAGIC is used to determine the intended CPU. Mainly use to determine how machine code should be interpret.

Comment: As Magic is already located inside optional header structure, it's likely bitness is defined before memory after IMAGE_FILE_HEADER will be "mapped" to 32 or 64 -bit kind of optional header struct.

Answer (score 0):

The Machine field will tell you the target platform, which includes its bitness, and the endianness of the section contents.  The PE header itself is little-endian (and the optional header is entirely optional for object files).